# D3 force layout with fixed nodes - what happens on "unfix"?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to use D3 force layout and fixed nodes (see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558).

This works fine (at least in Chrome). Try the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/vLXFb/

```
// Sticky Force Layout http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558
function nodeDblclick(d) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function nodeDragstartFixed(d, ths) {
    d3.select(ths).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

Drag the nodes around. When you stop dragging they will stick where you left them. You can unstick them by double-clicking on them.

However here is the problem: When you double-click and unstick a node the behaviour is strange. It looks like the node is still "hovered" (it is orange and bigger) until you move the mouse.

What is happening there? Is there some way to avoid it? Is it a bug in Chrome, or?

---

**UPDATE:** Here is a way I can reliably reproduce the problem with at the moment:
In the fiddle above:

1. Drag "cost" to top right.
2. "time" to bottom left.
3. "scope" to top left.
4. Now doubleclick "scope".

When I do this "scope" moves down towards middle-right bottom and stays there, orange and bigger (hover CSS conditions). When I move mouse "scope" moves into its place in the graph and the hover CSS conditions are removed.

UPDATE 2: Submitted a bug report, [Issue 373323 - chromium - CSS hover transform bad interaction with SVG](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373323)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff If you drag 2 nodes, stretches them apart a bit, and then doubleclick one of them to unstick that node, don't you see the strange behaviour I described above then?

Comment: No, nodes return to their normal black fill. Using Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. A bit strange. For me the doubleclicked node moves, but it moves a bit to far and retains the orange (hover) color and the bigger size. When I move the mouse the node moves to the correct location and size and the color changes to black. I am doing this with latest Chrome on Windows 7. What is your environment?

Comment: Chrome on Linux. I did notice some weirdness sometimes, but not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Could you please test again? See the instructions I added.

Comment: Since the hover CSS conditions does not have anything to do with D3 this must be a Chrome/Webkit bug then. I will repoort it.